# Request microphone Permission Flutter Web

Tags: html, flutter, navigator

I need to use microphone in my flutter web application. I tried the following code but it only works if i request `camera` .

```
final perm = await html.window.navigator.permissions.query({"name": "camera"});
    if (perm.state == "denied") {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text("Oops! Camera access denied!"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
      ));
      return;
    }
    final stream = await html.window.navigator.getUserMedia(video: true);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
PermissionStatus permission = await window.navigator.permissions.query({'name': 'microphone'});
```

now you know that you have permission or not.
granted if have permission and prompt if not.(or denied if blocked)
but in case of prompting dialog to get permission I use a trick and I send a request to get UserMedia for the first time and it's show the request dialog.

```
await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints);
```

As far as I know the browsers are not support for sending direct request for permission and you should use some tricks to show the dialog like above.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // ignore: avoid_web_libraries_in_flutter
import 'dart:html';

final permissions = await window.navigator
  .getUserMedia(
    audio: true,
  )
  .then((value) => true);
```

print('permissionss $permissionss');